# User.Identity.Name is always return my windows username

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I working on existing application. We are using ASP.NET MVC 4. 
When I start the authentication mode was Windows but I want change it into Form Authentication. I create Account controller and Login Action for authenticate user from database.   I did the following

First I configure Authentication mode into form in web.config file.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseUri"/>
</authentication>**
```

Second I enable Form Authentication on IIS server

Third I modified Global.ASP by the following code

```
void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            Entities db = new Entities();

            var name = User.Identity.Name;
            var key = "Roles." + name;
            var roles = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] as string[];
            if (roles == null)
            {

                //roles = db.GetRoles(HttpContext.Current.User.ToString()).ToArray();
                roles = db.GetRoles(name).ToArray();
                //HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(key);
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, roles, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

            }
            HttpContext.Current.User =
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal =
                    new GenericPrincipal(User.Identity, roles);

        }
```

my controller and action look like this

```
[Authorize]
```

// [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();
        Users users = new Users();
        //
        // GET: /Account/
        [AllowAnonymous]
       public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View(users);
        }

```
    // This Action is used to validate weather user is existing or not in a database
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Users user)
    {



        //Check Validation
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //In this Action we are doing Form Authentication
            //Check the entred username and passwords are proper or not
            int? flag = db.GET_USER(user.UserName, user.Password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (flag == 1)
            {
                //use Form Authentication class to set cookie
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Request.Form["txtUserName"], true);
                //@Session["username"] = user.FirstName;
                return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "The user name or password you entered is incorrect.";
                return View("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View("~/Views/Account/Login.cshtml");
        }

    }
```

But still "User.Identity.Name" property return my user name instead of the authenticated user's user name.
Is there anything I miss?

Thank you inadvance

Comment: It's not even possible to have both Windows and Forms auth simultaneously. I would check your Web.config and ensure that the authentication settings are actually what you think they should be. Your changes may not have saved, for example.

Comment: I don't actually see you caching the user name anywhere. 

You retrieve it from the database, but then just set the login cookie and don't store it anywhere. Then in your global ASP you just have a handle to `User`. Where is that coming from?

Comment: @AdmiralAdama  I'm new for dot.net. Do you have any idea what should I do. I mean where should I set User profile? And "User.Identity" is used for form authentication?
How can I set _User.Identity.Name_ property after the user is loged in.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I saved everything but I dont have any idea about **User.Identity.Name** property.